# list.where function not filtering

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm using this function as a boolean to enable or disable a button based on if a selection was made,

```
vehicleTypeSelectionList.where((item) => item.isSelected == true).isNotEmpty
```

however, even though the List has items where the bool isSelected to false (i debuged and checked all have isSelected=false). that code still returns the (full list).isNotEmpty (true) meaning that the button is enabled without a selection

what the heck am I doing wrong here?

Comment: the code looks GTM, probably issue is with the values in the list, or at least ``isSelected`` property. Try printing the list and isSelected value and check what value does it hold.

Comment: I don't need to print it. I debugged it and saw that the result was the full list even though all items have isSelected=fallse

Comment: ended up swapping for a for loop (same as any) and works fine. no idea why that where was having a mental breakdown but i sent him home

Comment: "no idea why that where was having a mental breakdown but i sent him home" - in such case it would mean a serious bug - notice that `where` is used in 1000s places in dart apps

Comment: not sure how that would help the question haha

Comment: i mean that `Iterable.where` works just fine, I gave you an example with the same code as yours and it was working without any problems, if you think it is not working post the whole, not working code

Answer (score 0):

you must use another method on your list .

this name is (ANY).
like this:

```
    bool activeButton = vehicleTypeSelectionList.any((element)=>element.isSelected == true);
```

then , any element of your list was true ,your boolean change to true.
;)

Comment: any and where do the same thing only any stops at the first.